# git log does not return result with case insensitive file name

Tags: git

My original file name is "mohanyadav.sql"

When I run below command then I am not getting result/output

```
git log --raw "**Mohanyadav.sql**"
```

where M is capital

but when I run below command then I get expected result

```
git log --raw "**mohanyadav.sql**"
```

where m is small which is exact same name of my file.

How can I get the same result with capital M?

Comment: Consider using a wrapper that could get the list of files that match a pattern and then run `git log` over the resulting list.

Answer (score 3):

The commits may have both `Mohanyadav.sql` and `mohanyadav.sql`, which have been added and committed in a case-sensitive system.

To tell Git to not care about case when matching a path, you can use [pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec) signature `icase`.

```
git log --raw -- ':(icase)Mohanyadav.sql'
# or
git log --raw -- ':(icase)mohanyadav.sql'
# or even
git log --raw -- ':(icase)mOHANyaDav.SQl'
```

If both `Mohanyadav.sql` and `mohanyadav.sql` exist in the history, all of their related commits are printed.

The standalone `--` is optional and recommended, especially in scripts. It disambiguates revisions and paths. Besides, if the path does not exist in the current working directory, the command does not result in errors.

Comment: git log --raw "**mohanyadav.sql**" => It return all files that has "mohanyadav.sql" text actuaaly we don know the exact path of a file that is why we user **somefiletext** pattern. 
The solution which you provided is not working with my pattern of file search like 
git log --raw -- ":(icase)Mohanyadav.sql" or git log --raw -- ":(icase)**Mohanyadav.sql**". I want to get all log of all file that has file names contains "mohan.yadav.sql".

Comment: @user2682332 Then try `git log --raw -- ':(icase,glob)**/Mohanyadav.sql'.

Comment: Thanks, it has been resolved @ElpieKay